# Creating a CKAN extension to display Page_View tracking summary for each dataset

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, ckan

```
  def get_dataset_tracking_summary(self, dataset_id):
    context = {'ignore_auth': True, 'use_cache': False}
    result = get_action('package_show')(context, {'id': dataset_id})
    tracking_summary = result.get('tracking_summary', {})
    return tracking_summary

    
 def update_config(self, config: CKANConfig):

    # Add this plugin's templates dir to CKAN's extra_template_paths, so
    # that CKAN will use this plugin's custom templates.
    # 'templates' is the path to the templates dir, relative to this
    # plugin.py file.
    toolkit.add_template_directory(config, 'templates')

def is_fallback(self):
    return True

def get_helpers(self):
    # Return the custom helper function in the template context
    return {
        'get_dataset_tracking_summary': self.get_dataset_tracking_summary
    }
```

written this code in plugin.py and below code to template file.
{% set tracking_summary = get_dataset_tracking_summary(package.id) %}

Views: {{ tracking_summary.total }}                                                                         but showing the error template not found and get_dataset_tracking_summary is undefined

I was expecting tracking_summary of dataset along with each dataset

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - the template not found error is raised because you aren't returning any/or the correctly named template from your route methods. See [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) to learn more.